# Angular6/Moment.js - InvalidPipeArgument / Invalid Date

Tags: angular, momentjs

My Angular6/moment.js app periodically emits error messages where it is unable to parse dates.  The issue clears when I restart PM2, which manages the server side Node.js component that retrieves the data.

I am using Angular6 with moment.js to handle dates and PM2 to manage the Node.js server side component.

Every couple of dates, my app starts emitting error messages related to parsing of dates.

The work-a-round I have implemented thus far is to restart PM2, which restarts the server side Node.js component.

This resolves the issue for another couple of days, then the errors recur.

I have reviewed the data returned by the server and the dates are correctly provided to the client, such as '03-MAY-17'

The error received is "InvalidPipeArgument':  Unable to convert '03-MAY-17' into a date for pipe 'e'.

[image: Sample Error Message]

Below are the two (2) ways the Angular code is parsing dates:

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="meeting_date">
  <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Target</mat-header-cell>
  <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">({{row.meeting_date | date:'M/dd/yyyy'}})</mat-cell>
</ng-container>


this.modifiedOn = moment(this.archActivity.last_mod_date).format('MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm:ss');
```

[image: Sample Error]

Comment: have you tried to standardize the date before passing it into the pipe? like passing it into `new Date()` so you can get a [ISO_8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601). doing some preprocessing might help with this error.

Comment: Have you try something like that: `{{ row.meeting_date | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy' }}`